# Group data by Custom Period Ranges Using a Reference Date and a Set Time Period

Tags: mysql

If for example, I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | volume |      createdAt      |
+----+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |   0.11 | 2018-01-26 13:56:01 |
|  2 |   0.34 | 2018-01-28 14:22:12 |
|  3 |   0.22 | 2018-03-11 11:01:12 |
|  4 |   0.19 | 2018-04-13 12:12:12 |
|  5 |   0.12 | 2014-04-21 19:12:11 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

I want to perform a query that can accept  starting point and then loop through a given number of days, and then group by that date range.

For instance, I'd like the result to look like this:

```
+------------+------------+--------+
| enddate    | startdate  | volume |
+------------+------------+--------+
| 2018-04-25 | 2018-04-12 |   0.31 |
| 2018-04-11 | 2018-03-29 |   0.00 |
| 2018-03-28 | 2018-03-15 |   0.00 |
| 2018-03-14 | 2018-03-01 |   0.22 |
| 2018-02-28 | 2018-02-15 |   0.00 |
| 2018-02-14 | 2018-02-01 |   0.00 |
| 2018-01-31 | 2018-01-18 |   0.45 |
| ...        | ...        |    ... |
+------------+------------+--------+
```

In essence, I want to be able to input a `start_date` e.g 2018-04-25, a `time_interval` e.g. 14, like in the illustration above and then the query will sum the volumes in that time range.

I know how to use `INTERVAL` with the `DATE_SUB()` and the `DATE_ADD()` functions but I cannot figure out how to perform the loop I think is necessary.

Please help.

Comment: why in second table start time is greater than end time?

Comment: @UdItSolanki It's a descending list. 
I suppose it can go the other way as well.

Comment: I can see no correlation between the data set and the result set.

Comment: @Strawberrythe data set is the table.
ID is the auto_increment value, volume is the measurement being stored and createdAt is  now(). 

The result set is basically trying to get the sum of volumes within the date ranges. To make the information easier to report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given data you can determine time based groupings using the datediff and floor functions:

```
floor(datediff(createdat, date '2018-04-25')/14) grp
```

From the group number you can determine the periods stardate and enddate:

```
date_add(date '2018-04-25', interval (grp*14) day) startdate
date_add(date '2018-04-25', interval ((grp+1)*14) day) enddate
```

Which represent a half open range with startdate being inclusive and enddate being exclusive.

Putting these together in a usable query:

```
select startdate, enddate, sum(volume)
  from (select t1.*
             , date_add(date '2018-04-25', interval (grp*14) day) startdate
             , date_add(date '2018-04-25', interval ((grp+1)*14) day) enddate
          from (select t.*
                     , datediff(t.createdat, date '2018-04-25') diff
                     , floor(datediff(t.createdat, date '2018-04-25')/14) grp
                from table1 t) t1) t2
 group by startdate, enddate
 order by startdate desc;
```

Unfortunately this does not get the empty periods.  To get the empty periods you need a way to generate rows.  However, MySQL doesn't have a simple way to generate rows (at least not until MySQL 8 where common table expressions and recursive SQL are added), but there are database objects that already have a large number of rows, such as the information_schema.columns view which likely has sufficient rows for your needs, and if it doesn't, a cross join or two will easily multiply the number of records generated.  That paired with a variable that increments for each row returned will provide the needed groups:

```
select @rn:=@rn+1 rn
     , stop
     , date_add(date '2018-04-25', interval (@rn*14) day) startdate
     , date_add(date '2018-04-25', interval ((@rn+1)*14) day) enddate
  from information_schema.columns c
     , (select @rn:=min(floor(datediff(createdat, date '2018-04-25')/14))-1
             , max(floor(datediff(createdat, date '2018-04-25')/14)) stop
          from table1) limits
 where @rn < stop;
```

Outer joining this with the original data and grouping by the period dates yields:

```
select startdate
     , enddate
     , sum(volume) volume
  from table1
  right join (
    select @rn:=@rn+1 rn
         , stop
         , date_add(date '2018-04-25', interval (@rn*14) day) startdate
         , date_add(date '2018-04-25', interval ((@rn+1)*14) day) enddate
      from information_schema.columns c
        -- , information_schema.columns d -- if needed add another cartesian join
         , (select @rn:=min(floor(datediff(createdat, date '2018-04-25')/14))-1
                 , max(floor(datediff(createdat, date '2018-04-25')/14)) stop
              from table1) limits
     where @rn < stop) periods
    on startdate <= createdat
    and createdat < enddate
  group by startdate, enddate
  order by startdate desc;
```

Take a look at the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69caf0/28) to see this in action

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do it determine start_date(which is the parameter you pass) and end_date from your entire table and loop through them by adding time interval.

Have a look at below stored routine:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getTotalVolumeByDateRange`(start_time timestamp, time_interval int)
BEGIN

DECLARE max_date date;
DECLARE min_date date;
DECLARE temp_end_date date;

SET min_date = DATE(start_time);
SELECT DATE(MAX(createdAt)) FROM VolumeData INTO max_date;

-- SELECT max_date, min_date;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempRangedVolumeData(
    start_date date,
    end_date date,
    Volume decimal(5,2)
);

while min_date <= max_date DO

    SET temp_end_date = DATE_ADD(min_date, Interval time_interval DAY);

    INSERT INTO tempRangedVolumeData(start_date, end_date, Volume)
    SELECT min_date, temp_end_date, SUM(Volume)
    FROM VolumeData
    WHERE DATE(CreatedAt) BETWEEN min_date and temp_end_date;

    SET min_date = DATE_ADD(min_date, Interval time_interval+1 DAY);

end while;

select 
    start_date,
    end_date,
    coalesce(Volume,0) as Volume
from tempRangedVolumeData;

drop table tempRangedVolumeData;
END
```

I hope this helps. Please comment if i am missing any edge case.